# How do I use Apollo to dedupe my GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using `apollo-client` with `apollo-link-http`. Here is the code to create my client

```
function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${process.env.URL}/app/graphql`,
      credentials: "same-origin"
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
}
```

I am making the same query multiple times on a page, expecting the dedupe to only allow the query to be sent up a single time. I have the query in a `.graphql` file and am calling the same file, so I know the query name and requested properties are exactly the same.

```
query getParcel($parcelId: Long) {
  parcel(id: $parcelId) {
      id
      name
  }
}
```

Here is the request I am making in my component, so you can see my `fetch-policy` is the default.

```
  let { data } = useQuery(GET_PARCEL, {
    variables: {
      parcelId
    }
  });
```

I can see many request for the same `parcelId` in the network tab and I verified that it is hitting the resolver each time.

Is there something else I have to do for the deduping to work? I was under the impression that it should work out of the box. What else I should look at?

Comment: how used in page? just useQuery multiple times, rendered in the same time? fetch-policy? query outside of page (in paretn), block rendering until data loaded

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: you can use fetch-policy 'cache-only' in each (-1) `useQuery`

Comment: ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/dedup/

Comment: Doesn't the link say that it is included by default?

Comment: means in default package, just import and compose with http link